# Error GET page request

Tags: go

I'm new to Golang and I'm trying to create a simple web server but I'm getting an error in a GET request. This is the code:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func sayhelloName(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseForm() 
    fmt.Println(r.Form) // print information on server side.
    fmt.Println("path", r.URL.Path)
    fmt.Println("scheme", r.URL.Scheme)
    fmt.Println(r.Form["url_long"])
    for k, v := range r.Form {
        fmt.Println("key:", k)
        fmt.Println("val:", strings.Join(v, ""))
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello Worrld!") // write data to response
}

func login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("method:", r.Method) //get request method
    if r.Method == "GET" {
        t, _ := template.ParseFiles("login.gtpl")
        t.Execute(w, nil)
    } else {
        r.ParseForm()
        // logic part of log in
        fmt.Println("username:", r.Form["username"])
        fmt.Println("password:", r.Form["password"])
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", sayhelloName) // setting router rule
    http.HandleFunc("/login", login)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9090", nil) // setting listening port
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("ListenAndServe: ", err)
    }
}
```

`sayhelloName` works but not the `login` function. This is the output error:

```
method: GET
2015/10/18 12:46:28 http: panic serving 127.0.0.1:51714: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
goroutine 6 [running]:
net/http.(*conn).serve.func1(0x1247aa20, 0xaf5380, 0x12490390)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1287 +0xa2
html/template.(*Template).escape(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/html/template/template.go:79 +0x37
html/template.(*Template).Execute(0x0, 0xaf54e8, 0x12530080, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    c:/go/src/html/template/template.go:101 +0x2b
main.login(0xaf5468, 0x12530080, 0x124f6620)
    C:/Users/Fabio/Go/hello.go:30 +0x209
net/http.HandlerFunc.ServeHTTP(0x7462e4, 0xaf5468, 0x12530080, 0x124f6620)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1422 +0x34
net/http.(*ServeMux).ServeHTTP(0x1252a020, 0xaf5468, 0x12530080, 0x124f6620)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1699 +0x133
net/http.serverHandler.ServeHTTP(0x12476480, 0xaf5468, 0x12530080, 0x124f6620)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1862 +0x156
net/http.(*conn).serve(0x1247aa20)
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1361 +0xc05
created by net/http.(*Server).Serve
    c:/go/src/net/http/server.go:1910 +0x343

login.gptl it's in the same folder of source code file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always handle your errors

```
 t, _ := template.ParseFiles("login.gtpl")
```

What if this fails? Then `t` is nil and you get the same error

Comment: Building on this: keep in mind that if you're using `go run` then the program may not be running from the same directory as your templates. Better to a) use absolute paths and b) parse templates in main() and not within every handler (which means you're reading from disk in every request).

Answer (score 0):

1. don't ignore error returned from template.ParseFiles
2. put path including directory into template.ParseFiles